# Apps coming as updated when recently installed

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-play-services, application-error

So, I recently downloaded myfitnesspal and when I did, it showed as updated and not installed. It said that the app was recently updated and not installed.

So my question is, is this normal sometimes and is anybody else having this problem? Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance for you reply!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine. Google Play Store will mark new installed app as 'Updated', there is none option for 'Newly Installed'.

Comment: But for other apps this does not happen. The other apps come in the 'installed' category.

Comment: Try to reboot your phone, but if you have that app instaled everything should be fine.